# Dropbox OAuth2 API always prompts user for permission when a refresh token is requested

Tags: oauth-2.0, dropbox

I'm writing an offline application that uses the Dropbox API. When a user comes to the application, I'm using the `https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token` ([docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-token)) to get a `refresh_token`, which I store for later use.

I am calling the same endpoint every time the user logs in (unless I've already got the user's data in a cookie). I'm not sure that this is the best way to go about it: I at least need to get the user's `account_id`, so that I can look up their `refresh_token` in the database if I already have it. But every time I call `https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token`, the user is redirected to the Dropbox app authorization interface, as if they've never approved the app before.

So I would either like to know how to stop Dropbox from forcing the user to re-authorize an app every time. Or, if that is just how `https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token` is supposed to work, I'd instead like to be able to get their `account_id` somehow when they visit my page.

(In case it's relevant, the app is still in development mode at this point.)

Answer (score 1):

The https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token endpoint is an OAuth endpoint that the app can call to get an access token/refresh token. Being an API endpoint, it does not itself redirect the user to the Dropbox app authorization page.

The Dropbox app authorization page is at https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize ([documented here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize)), and the app decides if/when to direct the user there to authorize the app.

You generally only need to send the user through the app authorization flow (sending them to https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize and then calling https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token) once per user for an "offline" application. Once you do so, you should store the resulting refresh token for that user. You'll typically store the refresh token for that user tied to their user account in your own app.

Exactly how you manage the user accounts in your own app will depend on how it's built, but, as it sounds like this is a web app, typically you would use the user's browser cookies to identify the user when they return to your page so that you can look them up in your database and retrieve their details, such as their corresponding refresh token. (Or, if they're not already signed in to your web app, you would have them do so first.)

Comment: That is a great, explanation, thank you. You're right that I was totally misunderstanding the role of `https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token`.

Answer (score 0):

Greg's answer is very helpful, and very politely addresses my misunderstanding of the auth flow. (I was revisiting old code I'd written years previously—obviously I should have documented it better than I had!)

In the end I believe that Dropbox was forcing me to reauthorize because my application was in development mode, and had a small user base. When I used the identical code in an app set to production mode, it stopped forcing me to reauthorize. So the “problem” is really a Dropbox security feature, and the solution was just to use production mode.